# are objects allocated without using "new" allocated on stack or heap

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ so question would be elementary.

Lets say I have defined a class Foo and I create a vector of vectors in the following code:

```
  namespace testme {
        class Foo {
           public:
            Foo(int x): x_(x) { };
            static vector<vector<int>> ReturnVecOfInts(int num) {
               vector<vector<int>> ret(num);
               for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                 vector<int> tmp;
                 ret.push_back(tmp);
                }
                return ret;
           }
  }
```

When i call:

```
    Foo::ReturnVecOfInts(5)
```

Is the vector of vectors created on heap or the stack. The reference is on the stack but I want to know whether it points to the heap since i want to return this object from a function.

This is important to me because clearly if these are allocated on the stack the vector of vectors would go out of scope and not usable outside the called function.

Comment: Depends entirely on where that declaration resides. If it's at namespace scope then the object has static storage duration, which is neither stack nor heap. By the way, please don't post fantasy code: post real code.

Comment: There aren't things like _stack_ or _heap_ defined in the c++ standard.

Comment: It depends on the system you are using.  That is why C++ has no notion of stack and heap and instead uses automatic and dynamic storage.

Comment: *Generally* if you're declaring that inside a function it's on the stack. If it's inside a heap-allocated object, that's on the heap as well. It depends highly on the context of where that statement appears.

Comment: So your real question is: *Is it safe to return a local object by value?*, yes?

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow Since you're using the wrong terms, your question is still unclear, sorry.

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow it looks like you're just confused about reference semantics vs value semantics. Unlike, say, Java or C#, writing `Foo f` creates a `Foo` object, not a `Foo` pointer/reference. Returning a `Foo` object doesn't mean returning a reference to one that is allocated somewhere, it returns the whole structure by value. This is how Java handles primitive types like `int`.

Comment: @RyanHaining I think you just cleared my confusion. But what happens if there are nested objects inside the objects. Are all of them retruned by value?

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow Some good reading on the topic: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow same logic applies, the nested object isn't a reference or pointer, it's actually part of the thing that contains it, returning an object by value means returning all of its members by value

Comment: Generally, if something is returned by value, it's safe to assume that the variable it's returned to will actually be copy or move constructed/assigned from the returned value, meaning that the caller will get its own copy, in its own memory space.  And technically, in most compilers, I believe the return value will actually be allocated at an address specified by the caller, due to a form of copy elision (special optimisation where copying is optimised out by just directly constructing the object at the address it would be copied to) known as RVO (return value optimisation).

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow: You can ignore the comments about terminology. They're not constructive. But nothing is allocated anywhere until you can get your code to compile. And SO readers (in particular myself) may be wary of answering a question that (1) has changed fundamentally, and (2) asks about the effect of code that won't compile. So start with that: post real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably overthinking.

In your case, you're safe in code like this:

```
Foo f = Bar::GetFoo();
```

When you return objects from functions, in general, there may occur various optimizations (e.g. RVO, NRVO, etc.), but the bottom line is that your `f` object is safe to use.

Even if inside Foo you have a data member like `std::vector` which usually allocates its memory from the heap (you can customize this behavior using custom allocators), thanks to copy constructors, move constructors, destructor, etc. you are totally safe in returning it from functions, or copying Foo instances around.

**EDIT** I noted that you changed your code after I wrote my answer, returning a `vector<vector<int>>` instead of `Foo`. Again, what I wrote still applies.

Comment: From @Ryan Haining's comment, I understand that c++ returns the actual object. Would returning vector<vector<int>> return a vector of references to vector<int> allocated on stack or vector of objects of the type vector<int> that would not go out of scope.

Comment: vector<vector<int>> is made by nested vectors. The inner vectors are vector<int>, and they allocate a contiguous block of ints from the heap with the default allocator. The outer vector is a vector of "vector<int>", so in this case the memory layout is more complex. But the bottom line is that returning vector<vector<int>> from functions is just fine, thanks to proper implementation details of std::vector.

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow Basically, a `vector` wraps and manages a dynamically allocated array; it's safe to assume that the array will be created on the heap (or equivalent), with the management part (which includes the array's address) on the stack (or equivalent); the management part is the only thing that needs to be returned, because the array won't be deallocated.  [Note that this applies to systems with a stack and a heap.  More esoteric systems may handle `std::vector` differently.  Also note that it may work differently than this in practice; this is just a simple description.]

Comment: Imagine it like this: You have a TV in your living room, and you & your friend are watching it.  You have the remote control.  If you want to let your friend be in charge of the TV, do you drop the TV itself in his lap, or just give him the remote?